# Android - Passing Intent from SherlockFragment to normal Activity class

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-fragments

I'm trying to pass two string into a normal class but I'm getting an error when I try to get the data

```
            final int a = i;
            blogs[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ReadBlog.class);
                    try {
                        i.putExtra("title", jsons[a].getString("title"));
                        i.putExtra("text", jsons[a].getString("text"));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    startActivity(i);
                    Log.e("button", "blog clicked");
                }
            });
```

And the normal class:

```
public class ReadBlog extends Activity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    setContentView(R.layout.readblog);
    String title = "title";// intent.getStringExtra("title");
    String text= "text";

    text = getIntent().getExtras().getString("text");

    TextView titlev = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    titlev.setText(title);

    TextView textv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textv.setText(text);

}
}
```

The `ReadBlog` class appears with the right text for a second before crashing - there is no error message, just the typical Android one that doesn't actually tell you what the problem is.

So what am I doing wrong?

```
07-24 22:12:37.130: E/pass 2.2(22138): blogs - connection success 
07-24 22:12:37.800: E/button(22138): blog clicked
07-24 22:12:37.830: W/dalvikvm(22138): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40f21438)
```

I don't think the data structure is a problem because it works fine when I print it to the screen, it's just the Intent that wont work.

Comment: post your logcat! and using for loop for json is PAIN. please use lists and defined classes with sub methods to add/get the values from.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you could pull the exception stack trace from the log.

I think I can tell from just the code what's going on, but it's a guess:

#### Part 1: cause

```java
try {    
    i.putExtra("title", jsons[a].getString("title"));
    i.putExtra("text", jsons[a].getString("text"));
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My guess is that `jsons[a].getString("title")` either throws an exception or returns null. Either way, no extras are added to the `Intent`. The intent works fine to start the other activity, but there are no extras in it.

#### Part 2: effect

```
text = getIntent().getExtras().getString("text");
```

If the intent has no extras, then `getExtras()` returns null. Therefore, the `.getString("text")` following it throws a NullPointerExcpetion. I believe this is the exception that causes "Unfortunately, your app has stopped.".

Post your logcat and we'll see if my theory holds.

Comment: pls see the changes I have made.

Comment: There should be a Java stack trace in your logcat somewhere. Please post that.